# How to get glyph metrics in C#

Tags: c#, fonts

I'm creating a `Font` object like this:

```
var font = new Font(font_name, font_size);
```

Where `font_name` is obtained from `System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families`. I render a char into an image using:

```
var char_renderer = Graphics.FromImage(char_image);
char_renderer.DrawString(ch.ToString(), font, new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0);
```

Is it possible to get the char metrics (advance, kerning, etc) only by having this information?

I've found in many places that I should use `System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface` to get the metrics, but I couldn't find any straight forward way to get to `GlyphTypeface` from `Font`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
// create typeface from font
var typeface = new Typeface("Arial");

// create glyphtypeface
typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out var glyphTypeface);

// retrieve metrics
glyphTypeface.AdvanceHeights.TryGetValue('S', out var advancedHeight);
```